# runtime error with open-mpi running hello_world on mac osx 10.8

Tags: macos, openmpi

I installed open-mpi-1.8.1 with homebrew and compiled the following hello world program with multi-threading successfully:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
  int world_size;
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
  int world_rank;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
  char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
  int name_len;
  MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &name_len);
  printf("Hello world from processor %s, rank %d out of %d processors\n",
         processor_name, world_rank, world_size);
  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

But when running it, I get a bunch of Symbol not found error, followed by segmentation fault. I also tried building open-mpi from source code directly both from 1.8.1 and 1.6.1, following the instruction [here](https://wiki.helsinki.fi/display/HUGG/Installing+Open+MPI+on+Mac+OS+X) and got the same errors. I have Xcode 5.1.1.

What can I do? Thanks in advance.

```
mpirun -n 4 ./mpi_hello_world

mca: base: component_find: unable to open /usr/local/lib/openmpi/mca_ess_slurmd: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/openmpi/mca_ess_slurmd.so, 9): Symbol not found: _orte_jmap_t_class
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/openmpi/mca_ess_slurmd.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
in /usr/local/lib/openmpi/mca_ess_slurmd.so (ignored)

mca: base: component_find: unable to open /usr/local/lib/openmpi/mca_errmgr_default: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/openmpi/mca_errmgr_default.so, 9): Symbol not found: _orte_errmgr_base_error_abort
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/openmpi/mca_errmgr_default.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/lib/openmpi/mca_errmgr_default.so (ignored)

mca: base: component_find: unable to open /usr/local/lib/openmpi/mca_routed_cm: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/openmpi/mca_routed_cm.so, 9): Symbol not found: _orte_message_event_t_class
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/openmpi/mca_routed_cm.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/lib/openmpi/mca_routed_cm.so (ignored)

...

*** Process received signal ***
Signal: Segmentation fault: 11 (11)
Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
Failing at address: 0x100000013
```

Comment: @Wesley: yours is the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have multiple versions of Open MPI installed at the same time. You should make sure that you cleanup all but one of them and just use a single one.

It is possible to have multiple MPI installations at the same time, but it requires you to be very careful about how you install them and set them up in your runtime environment.